# Rename file on WSL using `mv` produced error: "are the same file"?

Tags: windows-10, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using a work system (Windows-10) where I have activated WSL and installed Debian. I don't know if the IT Gods have done an update, but today using `mv` to [rename a file](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv) didn't work:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\pear> bash
[...]
[tart@PEAR plugins]$ mv handle_DailyAccountingSummary.py handle_dailyaccountingsummary.py
mv: 'handle_DailyAccountingSummary.py' and 'handle_dailyaccountingsummary.py' are the same file

[tart@PEAR plugins]$ ll
total 36K
drwxrwxrwx 1 tart tart 4.0K Sep 19 17:17 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 tart tart 4.0K Sep 19 17:17 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tart tart 5.3K Sep 19 17:17 handle_DailyAccountingSummary.py
```

**Why would that happen?**
(I even tried `--force`. I did rename my file with `mv Name.py name-bak.py`, and `mv name-bak.py name.py`, but WTF?)

UPDATE 2020-10-09:

I installed the new [Windows Terminal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/), and configured settings with my WSL Debian terminal as `"source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl".

Cleaning up a directory I tested the move (as rename) function (because I'm still amazed I hadn't noticed it before), and low and behold it worked:

```
[tart@RCB-PEAR Testing.d]$ dir
DailyAccountingSummary_09_25_2020.xlsx
[tart@RCB-PEAR Testing.d]$ mv DailyAccountingSummary_09_25_2020.xlsx DailyAccountingsummary_09_25_2020.xlsx
[tart@RCB-PEAR Testing.d]$ ls
DailyAccountingsummary_09_25_2020.xlsx
```

That's frustrating. I immediately tested PowerShell/WSL as noted above, and recreated the above error.

OH, so Windows Terminal doesn't have this issue? NOPE. Went back into the Windows Terminal to reverse the rename, and now Windows Terminal throws the same error:

```
[tart@RCB-PEAR Testing.d]$ ls
DailyAccountingsummary_09_25_2020.xlsx
[tart@RCB-PEAR Testing.d]$ mv DailyAccountingsummary_09_25_2020.xlsx DailyAccountingSummary_09_25_2020.xlsx
mv: 'DailyAccountingsummary_09_25_2020.xlsx' and 'DailyAccountingSummary_09_25_2020.xlsx' are the same file
```

What this the result of opening PowerShell and Windows Terminal?

- Close all terminals at the application level
- Reboot

neither restored to the previous state. No clue, but it is inconsistent.

Comment: I think it's about [case-sensitivity](https://superuser.com/a/431346/432690).

Comment: @kamil I’ve been using WSL for several years now developing Python scripts deployed on Win/Anaconda, and it never came up? I must be incredibly consistent naming files. (>_<)

Comment: If it helps, you can do this on Cygwin quite happily. `touch hello.txt; ls ?ello.txt; mv hello.txt Hello.txt; ls ?ello.txt` returns `hello.txt` and then `Hello.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're working on a case-insensitive file system.  Linux by default is case-sensitive, and file names are treated as simply a series of bytes.

The case this message is designed to catch is two files which are hardlinks.  On a Linux system, hardlinks are simply alternate names for the same inode and set of blocks on disk, and they are completely indistinguishable from each other.  Neither is a more privileged or more canonical name than the other.

When you attempt to perform a `rename(2)` system call and the two files are hardlinks to the same file, nothing happens, successfully.  However, this behavior is confusing: you still have both names, and maybe you expected the old name to now be absent, so something fails.  `mv` fails in this case because silently doing nothing is almost never the desired behavior.

However, in your case, you're actually working on a case-insensitive file system, which is not easily distinguishable from a file with many hardlinks that differ only in case.  (It is possible to distinguish if you list the directory contents, but that is not especially efficient.)  This is probably not heavily tested because it practically never comes up on a real Linux system.

Even though case-insensitive file systems are possible on Linux, it's [not possible to perform case folding correctly in a locale-insensitive way](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/turkish-i18n.html), and therefore there is probably not much interest in fixing issues with them, since these file systems are guaranteed to be broken for [more than 75 million people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_language).

In this case, you could file a bug report with your distro and ask them to handle this case more gracefully.  Doing so would involve a lot more system calls in this case (to enumerate the directory) and there was a series of patches in 2018 to remove system calls, so people might not be interested.  Then again, you never know unless you ask.